# Discord.js New "/" commands

Tags: discord, discord.js

Discord have recently booted out a new feature allowing you to add commands to the server. Pressing "/" on pc will bring up a little tab of commands. There is a feature for your bot to add to the list.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: "There is a feature for your bot to add to the list." Did they write this on an newsletter? This seems interesting but I wasn't able to find anything that said this feature existed

Comment: Such a feature hasn't recently been booted out... where did you hear about this? If it was on a newsletter or such, please include the link in your question!

Comment: This feature is still in beta. You can find more information in the Discord Developers server, #discord-api-announcements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently discord.js does not support slash commands. Advaith1 on GitHub has a tutorial on a workaround that you can read [here](https://gist.github.com/advaith1/287e69c3347ef5165c0dbde00aa305d2)